# Overriding equals method by a abstract class and set it as abstract so if any class extends, they must implement

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, overriding, abstract-methods

I'm trying to build an abstract class/interface that overrides methods that already exist and set them as abstract. Is this possible?

Code example:

```
public abstract class Box {
    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object o);
}
```

OR

```
public interface Box {
    @Override
    boolean equals(Object o);
}
```

Both of the class and interfaces above should have the same function, but does this mean both override Object equals method? even if I set it as abstract?

So will this work:

```
public class Tea extends Box {
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Buddy your concept are really shaken, I would suggest you to start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html tutorials with immediate effect.

Comment: @JornVernee You sure about that?

Comment: @chrylis Hmm, no, it seems to be true just for interfaces.

Comment: Note: Just remember that if you are overriding the equals() method, don't forget to override the hashCode() method as well. As a little reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, interfaces do not override methods.  So you cannot override `equals` from `Object` by adding an `equals` method to an interface.  Interfaces instead can be thought of as contracts, they guarantee that any non-abstract class implementing them will have all of the interfaces methods (either directly or through inheritance).

In regards to making a method abstract through inheritance, you can in fact do this.  So your example of overriding the `equals` method with an abstract definition in your abstract Box class will cause any classes extending `Box` to have to implement an `equals` method.

And as @OskarEmilsson commented, if you do this then you should also force `hashCode` to be implemented since equals and hashCode should be consistent with each other (equals objects must have equal hashCodes).